# Subset Axiom with a formula with two variables or more

Tags: set-theory

In the Subset Axiom:

> Let $\phi(x)$ be a formula. For every set $A$ there exists a set $S$ that consists of all the elements $x \in A$ such that $\phi(x)$ holds.

the formula $\phi(x)$ contains only one **free** variable ($\phi(x)$ could contain other **bounded variables** and **parameters**). Consider the following statement where $\phi$  is now a formula of two **free** variables $\phi(x, y)$.

> Let $\phi(x, y)$ be a formula. For every set $A$ there exists a set $S$ that consists of all the elements $x \in A \text{ and } y \in A$ such that $\phi(x, y)$ holds.

Will the axiom and the above statement be compatible with each other? By compatible I mean no contradiction arises when both are true.

Comment: What "type" of elements are the elements of $S$? Are they ordered pairs $(x, y)$ with $x, y\in A$, or is $S$ still a subset of $A$, or something else?

Comment: See [Axiom Schema of Separation Parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2173317/axiom-schema-of-separation-parameters) as well as [Parameters in the ZFC axioms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040647/parameters-in-the-zfc-axioms).

Comment: Also [Axiom schema of specification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/633233/axiom-schema-of-specification-formula-arguments).

Comment: @Arthur There's no any requirement on $S$ except it's a set, $\phi(x, y)$ is a formula of two free variables $x$ and $y$ and not of a single free variable of an order pair $(x, y)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I've sifted through your posted links but still couldn't get it. I'm aware of bounded variables and parameters could appear in $\phi(x)$ but I'm interested in multiple **free** variables only.

Answer (score 0):

The statement can be shown to be true based on the Subset Axiom. We can write the collection $S$ in the statement in set notation as follows:

$S=\{x\in A, y \in A: \phi(x, y)\}$

To show that $S$ is a set, observe that:

$
\begin{align}
\{x\in A, y \in A: \phi(x, y)\}&=\{x: (\exists{y}\in A)\phi(x, y)\} \bigcup \{y: (\exists{x}\in A)\phi(x, y)\}\\
&=\{\exists{y}\in A: \phi^{'}(x)\} \bigcup \{y\in A: \phi^{''}(y)\}\\&(\text{where }\phi^{'}(x)=(\exists{y}\in A)\phi(x, y)\text{ and }\phi^{''}(y)=(\exists{x}\in A)\phi(x, y))\\&=(\exists{x}\in A)\phi(x, y)
\end{align}
$

Since both $\{x \in A: \phi^{'}(x)\}$ and $\{y \in A: \phi^{''}(y)\}$ are sets according to the Subset Axiom, and the union of them is also a set. So, $S$ is a set.